# How can keep my existing rewrite rules working with a WordPress install?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I had a pretty simple website that had some static pages, but also some dynamic pages that use rewrite rules to pull data in. For instance:

```
RewriteRule ^phone-directory/([^/\.]+).htm$ number.php?for=$1 [L]
```

So any urls like: **phone-directory/google.htm** would always load **number.php** with **google** on the query string.

I have installed WordPress for the CMS capabilities but I still need my directory working at the same time. I also want the directory to use the WordPress theme so that styling changes are site wide!

So I set up a custom template in my WP theme directory, and set up a "page" in word press called "company-listing". I then added the following rule to the top of my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^phone-directory/([^/\.]+).htm$ index.php?p=23 [L]
```

p=23 refers to the location of my custom page "company-listing"

That rewrite rule works and takes me to "company-listing", but that's the problem, the URL rewrites to domain.com/company-listing

I don't want it to do that. I think my rewrite rule is triggered, then when index.php?p=23 gets hit the default WordPress rewrite rule triggers. I have tried the following exludes to stop this from happening with no joy:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(phone-directory/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php?p=23)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(company-listing/.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any way round this? To use a custom template in WordPress and rewrite to a url of my choice? In summary:

I want:

**domain.com/phone-directory/google.htm**

to load:

**domain.com/index.php?p=23** (this is a "page" in wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have your rules before your wordpress rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^phone-directory/([^/\.]+).htm$ number.php?for=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^phone-directory/google.htm$ index.php?p=23 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If one of the earlier rules matches, as long as `number.php` exists, the `!-f` condition for wordpress' routing rule will fail.

Comment: Hi Jon. The problem is, when index.php?p=23 gets hit.... that's then a match for the wordpress rules further down. That's why from index.php?p=23 the url ends up on /company-listing as it's a wordpress page.

Comment: @JamesWilson `/index.php?p=23` will match `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`, which just stops rewriting completely. If the browser is getting redirected, it's because wordpress is doing it.

Comment: Yes agreed. I have managed a work around. I have set my rewrites to hit a new page called "directory-listing.php" and on that page there is some code which does a file_get_contents of index.php?p=23 - So it suck in the right content and I dynamically change it, without any further redirection!